# Angular1 Scope variables in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular, typescript

I am using **scope.$on, scope.$watch,scope.$broadcast, $scope.$apply,$scope.$emit. etc,** in `angular1`. but when i try to write my code in `angular2`, i heard these properties are not valid in `angular2`. so anyone suggest substitute for those kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you mentioned exists in Angular2.
In Angular2 you use services and observables instead.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service